# Fheatmap error message and data file

Tags: r, heatmap

I am starting with R trying to make a heatmap of 41,000 coordinate pairs.  They are arranged in simple text file which I imported into R as V1 and v2.

To begin exploring the `fheatmap` command and functions, I simply used

```
fheatmap(test)
```

where test is the name of my data.  I receive the following error.

> Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_setviewport, vp, TRUE) :
>     non-finite location and/or size for viewport
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In max(unlist(length_npc(list_name = row_names, dim = "width", font_size = row_fontsize))) :
>     no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

If anyone has experience with this function I would appreciate some guidance.

Edit: The "heat" would be based on the frequency of XY points that occupy a common space. In addition to learning about R, my ultimate goal is to cross validate a heatmap produced by my own C# code with something else.
[heatmap in my C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGm8t.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Please import following external libraries and then try using "fheatmap"
Imports: grid, RColorBrewer , gdata, ggplot2, reshape2, plots

Like the following
library(grid)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(gdata)
library(ggplot2)
library(plots)
library(reshape2)

If above libraries are not already installed , use following command install.packages("ggplot2") to install all the packages.

Comment: Hello Dream Sentisci and welcome to SO. When giving an answer try to be a little more verbose, such as how to import these libraries (OP is an R novice, apparently) and how to issue the command.